# SQL Server: Return columns in a specific time interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I want to return the rows between a specific time interval, i.e. between 01:00:00 and 01:05:00, and then calculate the sum of another column.
The column data type is TIME. I tried 'between...and' command but it didn't work.

Moreover, I want to do the same calculation for every five minutes.

**EDIT:**

My query that didn't work

```
select time
from dbo.table;
where time between'01:00:00' and '01:05:00'
```

Error message: *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.*

Sample Data:

```
Time      ----- Team
01:00:00  ----- Liverpool
01:06:33  ----- Liverpool
01:04:00  ----- Man. United
01:02:17  ----- Man. City
01:01:00  ----- Man. City
01:07:15  ----- Liverpool
```

My expected output, I would like to be something like

```
[01:00:00 - 01:05:00] ----- Man. City ----- 2
[01:00:00 - 01:05:00] ----- Liverpool ----- 1
[01:00:00 - 01:05:00] ----- Man. United ----- 1
[01:05:01 - 01:10:00] ----- Liverpool ----- 2
```

Finally, I want a loop for 2-3 hours.

Comment: Show us your query that didn't work.

Comment: Your attempt so far?? Any Sample Data??? expected output from that sample data???

Comment: "I want to do the same calculation for every five minutes."  Until what time? 24 hours?

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient post
@TabAlleman I put the code that didn't work.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon after `dbo.table` and try your query again.

Comment: @M.Ali I put a small part of my data, I hope to help.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli It is for 2-3 hours. I don't know if there is any difference in SQL, for example in another language the for loop could be the same either for 3 or for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you you use `between` to define a time range both the lower and upper points of that range are included. To avoid range overlaps simply define time ranges with a combination of `>=` and `<` instead.

```
select [time]
from dbo.table
where [time] >= '01:00:00' and [time] < '01:05:00'
```

This is even more important when using case expressions dealing with multiiple ranges so that they are mutually exclusive.

```
 Select
   case 
    when [time] >= '01:00:00' and [time] < '01:05:00' then  '[01:00:00 - 01:05:00]'
    when [time] >= '01:05:00' and [time] < '01:10:00' then  '[01:05:00 - 01:10:00]'
    ...
    end
From dbo.table
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no doubt that there is a way to calculate your time intervals, but I'd have to search how to do that. If your time intervals are going to be static then you can create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeIntervals](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStart] [TIME](0) NOT NULL,
    [TimeEnd] [TIME](0) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Your records would look like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[TimeIntervals] ([TimeStart], [TimeEnd]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:00:00' AS Time), CAST(N'01:05:00' AS Time))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TimeIntervals] ([TimeStart], [TimeEnd]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:05:00' AS Time), CAST(N'01:10:00' AS Time))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TimeIntervals] ([TimeStart], [TimeEnd]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:10:00' AS Time), CAST(N'01:15:00' AS Time))
GO
```

I also created a table to hold your example values:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Times](
    [times] [TIME](7) NULL,
    [team] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:00:00' AS Time), N'Liverpool')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:06:33' AS Time), N'Liverpool')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:04:00' AS Time), N'Man. United')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:02:17' AS Time), N'Man. City')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:01:00' AS Time), N'Man. City')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Times] ([times], [team]) VALUES (CAST(N'01:07:15' AS Time), N'Liverpool')
GO
```

Then your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
      ti.TimeStart
     ,ti.TimeEnd
     ,t.team
     ,COUNT(t.team)
FROM dbo.Times t
    INNER JOIN dbo.TimeIntervals ti ON t.times BETWEEN ti.TimeStart AND ti.TimeEnd
GROUP BY ti.TimeStart
    ,ti.TimeEnd
    ,t.team
```